# How to use jquery on HTML loaded after document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several HTML elements, that are rendered by a javascript function on the page:

```
<a href="#" class="test1">Test</a>
<a href="#" class="test2">Test</a>
<a href="#" class="test3">Test</a>
```

I then have further javascript that I use to create a function when Test is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $( ".test1" ).click(function() {
   // Code here
   });

   $( ".test2" ).click(function() {
   // Different code here
   });

   $( ".test3" ).click(function() {
   // Different code here
   });

});
```

However, because the HTML inserted is not loaded at the same time the page loads (it is dynamically inserted after), my click function doesn't capture the event. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document)
        .on('click', '.test1', function() {
            // Code here
        })
        .on('click', '.test2', function() {
            // Code here
        })
        .on('click', '.test3', function() {
            // Code here
        });
});
```

Note, for best performance `document` should be changed to the closest static parent element which is available on DOM load.

Comment: If I have a whole bunch of functions, can I nest them under (document).on? If so, what would be the syntax?

Comment: It depends on the structure of those functions, and how logic flows between them. Can you edit your question to include those functions.

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't seem to solve my problem. What's the best way to debug it?

Comment: The same as all javascript - the console. Press F12 in your browser to see it.

Comment: Just to be clear, you still need your document ready handler. Check my update

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function() { //code here });
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Comment: Thanks, why use (document).ready at all then? What are the advantages/disadvantages of this?

Comment: @alias51 Read [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your click events "live", so they attach to objects as they are introduced to the dom. 
Just change 
    .click(function(){ .... });
to
    .live('click', function(){ .... });

Comment: No, no. `.live()` has been deprecated. Use `.on()` instead.